# How do you describe someone who does not eat those food they dislikes?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

Some people can be very picky about food, they may not eat any of the food they dislike. How do you describe this type of people except picky eaters?

Comment: how is 'How do you describe someone who does not eat those food they dislikes?' different from 'What's another term for picky eater?' given you realise 'picky eater' is an answer to the 1st question?

Comment: I don't like shellfish, so I don't eat them, but I am definitely not a 'picky eater'. There is no special word for somebody who doesn't eat something.

Comment: Is there a word for this concept in your language that's distinct from "picky eater"? How do dictionaries translate it into English?

Comment: [this type of person, these types of people//any of the foods they dislike]

Comment: If it is a feeding or eating disturbance, depending on the type you can use "Avoidant/restrictive food intake disorder(ARFID)" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoidant/restrictive_food_intake_disorder or "Orthorexia nervosa" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthorexia_nervosa .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to someone as a "picky eater" is correct and idiomatic. You might also use the adjective "finicky" to describe such a person. There is no single word in English that denotes this idea that I am aware of. However, when the context of eating is well understood simply using the words "picky", "finicky", "fussy", or "demanding" work fine.

For example "at lunch the child was often finicky".

Comment: Might be worth considering that words like 'picky', 'finicky', 'fussy', or 'demanding' are all fairly pejorative and judgemental/opinion based. I might add 'faddy'. They can be contrasted with 'sensible', 'healthy', 'discriminating', etc, which are also opinion-based, but biased the opposite way. I don't eat 'junk' (highly processed) food if I can help it, and have been called 'fussy' by pizza and burger chain fans, but I believe I know who will live longer.